# DataFrame.to_csv() not working in IPython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

After updating various packages (I'm running the Anaconda Python distribution) `DataFrame.to_csv()` will not work from within IPython Notebook. Everything else Pandas-related seems to work fine (reading data into datframes, manipulating them, etc.) but `DataFrame.to_csv()` will *not* generate an output file. A snippet of the code:

```
hives_output = hives_data.groupby(['user_id','replay']).apply(hives_processor).sort(['user_id','replay'])
hives_output.to_csv('hives_output.csv',index=False)
```

The first command runs fine,  but no output file is produced by the second command. *No error is produced whatsoever*.

Weirder still, the code runs fine (i.e. it does generate an output file) within a regular Python or IPython interpreter, or when run from the command line, so the problem would seem to be specific to IPython Notebook.

I've tried downgrading various packages, but have yet to isolate the problem. Has anyone experienced this? Any ideas on what might be the cause? Some sort of incompatibility between IPython-Notebook and Pandas?

Comment: well it probably IS generating an output, file, but in the current directly of where you started the server :)

Comment: Nope...that's the first thing I checked.

Comment: print out the frame before your write it. maybe their is some other error.

Comment: What do you get if you run `%cwd` in the notebook just after that? I agree with @Jeff - it seems most likely that it is writing a file, just not in the location you expect.

Comment: Sorry everyone, this apparently was a problem with Finder on my Mac (???). The files simply weren't showing up in the finder window but were visible from the command line. Bizarre. Problem solved.